# Unexplained 504 while making requests from Angular app to Service inside K8s Cluster

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, httpclient, aws-api-gateway

I have an Angular 6 app deployed in S3 deployed using Cloudfront .

My Backend looks like this

> ```
> API GATEWAY ====> LoadBalancer ====> K8s Cluster ====> Service
> ```

For certain instances, my requests return a 504. They do not get logged in the service at that time. I am confused as to why that happens. The requests do get logged at Api Gateway. After repeated attempts, the request gets successfully executed and logged at the service level. I cannot explain as to why this happens when I make these requests from the app. The same requests made from POSTMAN seem to work in one go. I am using the `HttpClient` to make my requests. The problem is with it randomly working. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors when requesting on the App? You could be getting a CORS error for instance. Just wanted to make sure if that's the case.

Comment: Is there any kind of request spike happening at the time?

Comment: @SiddAjmera nope . It looks like the request doesn't reach the service from the API gateway . Hence the api gateway wait for a response and it times out . And on the app i get a 504 . The problem is i don't know if i can see the requests being forwarded from gateway to NLB . No Cors error. CORS is enabled .

Comment: @LevKuznetsov nope . just making isolated requests . no spike . Plus the service is on auto scale

Comment: @Jeson Dias "The problem is i don't know if i can see the requests being forwarded from gateway to NLB" -> can you check metrics associated with your NLB ?